# EF6 Migrations w/ FirebirdClient Failing. "Index IX_Id already exists"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, code-generation, firebird

Trying to use the code-first approach with entityframework 6 / firebird ADO.NET provider. I'm using **TPT inheritance**.

When generating the **initial** migration script (the first migration), I get the doomed `IX_ID already exists` error.

I'm using TPT inheritance, so there will be 3 tables : Locator, AddressLocator and TelephoneLocator. It seems that EF6 tries to create indexes for each of these tables (which is perfectly ok), but they all have the same name. That's what's failing.

Check the last line of the SQL code I put below to see the actual error.

How can I fix this, either by changing the index names (prefixing them with the table name perhaps?)

Repo for the project : https://github.com/ludydoo/ef6firebirdindex

This is a simplified representation of what my schema looks like

```
namespace MyModel

    public partial Locator {
        public Guid Id {get; set;}
    }

    public partial AddressLocator : Locator{
        public string NameB {get; set;}
    }

    public partial TelephoneLocator : Locator{
        public string NameC {get; set;}
    }

    public partial class MyModel : DbContext
    {
        // ...

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder b)
        {
            b.Entity<AddressLocator).ToTable("AddLoc");
            b.Entity<TelephoneLocator>().ToTable("TelLoc")
        }
    }
```

See model definition here : https://gist.github.com/ludydoo/fc129e69fd7807eda3c1

Then, I can successfully generate the migration script (this is the initial script, none has been added before).

I'm attaching the full script here https://gist.github.com/ludydoo/08239cd99b56150bdc85.

When I run the update-database, I get this error :

```
unsuccessful metadata update
Index IX_Id already exists
```

This is the SQL that has been executed https://gist.github.com/ludydoo/f4e9e465831dee5b1dee

The last part causes the error :

```
CREATE TABLE "L_ADD" (
    "Id" CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET OCTETS NOT NULL, 
    "ADD_ID" CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET OCTETS NOT NULL, 
    "L_ADD_T_ID" CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET OCTETS NOT NULL, 
    "Discriminator" VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
)
ALTER TABLE "L_ADD" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_L_ADD" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
CREATE INDEX "IX_Id" ON "L_ADD"("Id") // 1st IX_Id
CREATE INDEX "IX_ADD_ID" ON "L_ADD"("ADD_ID")
CREATE INDEX "IX_L_ADD_T_ID" ON "L_ADD"("L_ADD_T_ID")
CREATE TABLE "L_TEL" (
    "Id" CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET OCTETS NOT NULL, 
    "TEL_ID" CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET OCTETS NOT NULL, 
    "L_TEL_T_ID" CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET OCTETS NOT NULL, 
    "Discriminator" VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
)
ALTER TABLE "L_TEL" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_L_TEL" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
CREATE INDEX "IX_Id" ON "L_TEL"("Id") // 2nd IX_Id
```

I installed the latest versions of

- EntityFramework 6.1.3
- .NET framework 4.6.1
- FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient and EntityFramework.Firebird v4.9.0.0

Comment: Do you have a DBSet for each table in your MyModel class? You need this for TPT.

Comment: That did not solve it...

Comment: Is that IX_Id automatically generated by entity framework? It is entirely unnecessary as in Firebird the primary key (and foreign key for that matter) automatically get an index.